# Meaning of "pro" before a noun

Tags: meaning, nouns, prefixes

First, is "pro" an abbreviated form of "professional"? If yes, does "Pro American" mean "Professional American"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the three meanings of *pro*:

- (noun) *professional*. Example: *Don't mess with me. I'm a pro!*
- (noun) *advantage*. Used mainly within the context of *pros and cons (advantages and disadvantages)*. Example: *The pros of democratic governance far outweigh the cons*.
- (preposition/adverb) *in support of*. Example: *I'm a pro-choice activist.*

In your example, *pro-American* is an adjective (*pro* functions as a preposition here), and as such, it should always be hyphenated. Example: *His views are definitely pro-American*. On the other hand, *pro America* is an adverbial phrase and it should not be hyphenated. Example: *The Non-Aligned Movement has never been pro America*.

Comment: protip: being pro-American has a lot of pros.

Comment: @Eric, and if one of those pros was that you had a paid job promoting American interests, you'd be a pro pro-American. (Note given the purpose of this website, that was a deliberately silly use of English as a joke).

Answer (score 5):

No, in the usage you describe, *pro* means *in favor of* or a *proponent of*.  I believe the etymology is simply that *pro* is Latin meaning *for*.

So if someone is Pro American, it would mean that they have a favorable opinion of America in some context.

*Edit: I'll note the opposite is normally anti.  Anti-American sentiments would be those that are unfavorable to America*

Comment: Agreed. However, the usage of "pro" meaning "in favor of" is usually followed by a dash, as in "pro-American". Note the difference between a "pro football group" and a "pro-football group".

Comment: @Dour High Arch - excellent point.

Comment: Why no? Is "pro" (Professional) an adj.? If yes, why we can't say "pro american" or "pro people"?

Comment: @kikio - "pro" as an abbreviation of professional is not used universally in adjective form.  It is mostly restricted to the use of professional ranking in sports (i.e. not amateur) or other fields by analogy (e.g. `he's a pro  pianist`).  If you were to say `He is a pro person` that would be strange and mean something more along the lines of `he's an expert at being a person` rather than what you probably mean `He works as a professional`.

Comment: @kikio -  I'll also point out that `pro-American` is a fairly common phrase (meaning in favor of America) and so if you said `He's a pro American` I assume you'd made a typo of `He's pro-American` rather than `He's a professional American`

Comment: OK. Finally, Can I say: "Professional American Designers" and "Pro American Designers" (or "Pro- American Designers") ??? Thanks